# Bootstrap 3 legacy browser support?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3

I developed a website using Bootstrap 3. How would I go about supporting older browsers as a fallback? I was considering using Bootstrap 2 as the fallback. Would that be good, or is there an extension to Bootstrap 3 that makes it compatible with older versions of IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 is mostly compatible from Internet Explorer 8 onwards, you do however need to add the Respond.js polyfill to get the responsive grid to work. See [nternet Explorer 8 and 9](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-ie9) in Bootstraps documentation for more information.

As Bootstrap 2 would only add support for Internet Explorer 7 you really need to ask yourself which browsers you want to support. See caniuse.com's [Browser usage table](http://caniuse.com/usage_table.php) for global usage statistics on browsers. Adding support for Internet Explorer 7 only would only allow for an additional 0.08% of global users to use your website. The statistics for your country might differ though.

As for combining Bootstrap 2 and Bootstrap 3 classes in the same html I think you'll find issues. The [Migrating to 3.x](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.1.1/docs/migration/) guide might be the best start to find potential issues.

Comment: FWIW, there is a third-party add-on for IE7 support: https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-ie7